# Compare date in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

### Task:

I need to check the current time with a respective time fixed by the admin, if the current time crosses the respective time, will update status

1) How can i convert the respective date to unix timestamp ?

TIME STAMP:  1267285500 for DATE:  2 / 27 / 2010 @ 9:45:0

so that i can compare the unix timestamps of the current time and respective time and update the status

2) Is there any easy way that i can acheive this task ?

Thank You,

Comment: Have a look at http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

You may use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) and [strftime](https://www.php.net/strftime) (to get a valid input for strtotime) then get a unix timestamp, and compare them.

Also, you can use [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get back from a unix timestamp to a formated date.

Answer (score 0):

```
strptime('2 / 27 / 2010 @ 9:45:0', '%m / %e / %Y @ %T'); // This might not work.
```

Whoever decided that they where not going to use leading zeros kinda screwed you on this one. You might have to parse the date some more to get a full result like this:

```
list($date, $time) = explode(' @ ', '2 / 27 / 2010 @ 9:45:0');
list($month, $day, $year) = explode(' / ', $date);
list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);

$unixtime = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
```